# Best practice for reusing Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, layout

I recently laid out a fairly simple quiz question with jQuery (show / hide, addclass and a variable to count attempts and respond if attempts = 2), and I'm trying to figure out the best practice for replicating the same code on multiple questions. Would the best practice be to change all the variables for both the HTML layout and the jQuery? Or is there a more efficient way to add a second / third.. etc question?

Here's how I laid out the first question.

```
<form class="ra">
<div class="cor">
    <input type="radio" name="question1" class="c1" />A. Choice A<span class="hiddencorr">Correct answer</span>

</div>
<div class="inc">
    <input type="radio" name="question1" class="i1" />B. Choice B<span class="incorr">Your choice</span>
</div>
<div class="inc">
    <input type="radio" name="question1" class="i2" />C. Choice C<span class="incorr">Your choice</span>
</div>
<div class="inc">
    <input type="radio" name="question1" class="i3" />D. Choice D<span class="incorr">Your choice</span>
</div>
<div class="inc">
    <input type="radio" name="question1" class="i4" />E. Choice E<span class="incorr">Your choice</span>
</div>
</form>
<p class="rationale1"><b>Rationale:</b> 
<br />
<br /><span class="rattext">Explanation of what was done wrong.</span>

</p>
<button id="radiochk1" class="checkhide">Check your answer</button>
<button id="resetq1" class="reset">Reset</button>
```

JS / CSS & functionality in fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/YSSWL/97/

Answer (score 1):

Class values related to initial style and layout typically should not differ among like elements (though those indicating state could). Instead, increment your name and ID attributes using jQuery, similarly to what you're doing now for class.

Comment: I couldn't trouble you for a simplified explanation of incrementing attributes via jquery could I, or perhaps a small tangible example? Not sure if you mean manually increment the values or increment them via a variable like I handled the number of clicks.

Comment: You're already using a counter in your example. Just append its value to the id and name values of each new element as they're created: $(this).attr('id', 'my_id_name_' + counter);

Comment: I'm going to have a tough time giving specifics without knowing more about how you want to add questions, etc. Here's not a great place for that conversation.